# How to use ajax in reactjs on localhost

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Below is my code:
While using local url I am getting the error

***"Failed to load http://localhost/reactjs/my-app/lib/ajax.php: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access"***

But when I used live url such as "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos" its working fine.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/reactjs/lib/ajax.php',
//url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
 type: 'GET',
dataType: 'jsonp',
//contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//jsonp: "json_callback",
crossOrigin: true,
//cors: true,
//data: {user_name:username, user_type: usertype, password: password,mode: 'Login' },
success: function(data){
alert(data);
},
error: function(error){
console.log(error);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on php side :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

And this url `http://localhost/reactjs/my-app/lib/ajax.php` should be `http://localhost/reactjs/lib/ajax.php`

Comment: Added but still getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" while using localhost

Comment: My reactjs folder is wamp/www/reactjs/my-app and my php code in
wamp/www/reactjs/lib/ajax.php

Comment: You don't need to set this headers if you are on same host... Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You are calling different host so that's why you have CORS issue. Your application is running on `localhost:3000` and you are calling your service on `localhost`.

You can do what Vivek suggests (if it is different host) or you just need to have proper port referenced (if both applications are on localhost:3000).

Note that you don't have to write absolute url in ajax. Instead, if it is on same host, you could just write `/reactjs/lib/ajax.php`.

Comment: How can I make both on same port as I am new in reactjs,

I tried what Vivek said but not worked.

Comment: What is the url(host) of the server running code above? This has nothing to do with React...

Comment: Reactjs running on: http://localhost:3000/
Php: http://localhost/reactjs/lib/ajax.php

Comment: Then the solution from Vivek is correct and you should follow along with it.